# A redirecting site (dereferrer) like anonym.to in PHP - Check URL parameter - Security?

Tags: php, security, url, referrer

I wand to build a simple dereferrer site like anonym.to

When you visit http://www.mydereferrer.tld/?http://www.sitename.tld you should be redirected to http://www.sitename.tld by a meta-refesh tag.

Here's what I have:

```
<?
if(($pos = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')) !== false) {
    $url = trim(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $pos + 1));
}
if (strlen($url) > 50) {
    $url_short = substr($url, 0, 48) . "..";
} else {
    $url_short = $url;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?
if(!empty($url)) { 
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=<? echo $url ?>" />
<?
}
?>
<title>.. Redirecting</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <?
        if (isset($url)) {
        ?>
        <h1>.. Redirecting</h1>
        <p><a href="<? echo $url; ?>"><? echo $url_short; ?></a></p>
        <?
        } else {
        ?>
        <h1>.. No valid URL given</h1>
        <?
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this works quite fine. But what security checks should I do?

Comment: You should not do “checks” – you should treat data for the _context_ you are putting it into accordingly, each time that happens for a new context.

Comment: (OK, you should maybe do _one_ check – that the redirect target is not your redirecting URL itself again, so that no one can create an endless loop …)

Answer (score 1):

What CBroe is referring to is that you just include `$url` and `$url_short` without any character escaping. Because of that you are susceptible to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29). As a quick example assume `$url` is

```
www.google.com" /><body onload=alert('test1')><br style="
```

then

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=<? echo $url ?>" />
```

gets evaluated to

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=www.google.com" /><body onload=alert('test1')><br style="" />
```

[OWASP has an excellent guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) on how you embed untrusted data into your page.

Comment: So for $url_short i can use `htmlspecialchars($url_short)`, but for $url it seems to be tricky to encode the whole url..

Comment: As far as I know `htmlspecialchars` is not function written with security in mind (like much of PHP unfortunately). A simple solution (inspired by the linked OWASP guide) is to replace *every* char below 256 with the corresponding `&#xHH` escape sequence and remove every other char completely.